# Keep path when rewriting with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I recently moved my webpage from HTTP to HTTPS and I now got a couple of things that doesn't work like before.

The problem I'm having is that when a user is trying to go to: 
`http://example.com/i/<imageID>` they are redirected to:`https://www.example.com/i/image.php?id=<imageID>`. This is "correct", but not what I want. I want the links to stay at `/i/<imageID>` regardless of the user came from http or https.

I have two .htaccess-files that I use to control this redirection on my webpage.

First .htaccess (root directory):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Second .htaccess (image directory - /i):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)$ image.php?img=$1 [NC,L]
```

This redirection was working just fine before I added the first .htaccess-file that redirects the user from HTTP to HTTPS, but now it seems to be broken.

I'm not that familiar with htaccess-files so I hope someone out there can help so I can get my clean URLs back. :)

Comment: Did it work now? ^^

Comment: @Hello-Fishy I'm afraid not. Now I'm getting a 404-code.

Comment: Where did it go wrong this time? :D I'm not giving up yet ;) Plz tell me which pattern you tried to call, what the expected and the actual result was. thx

Comment: When I added your updated code (without the proxy-thing) and tried go to for example `http://matsa.no/i/ph1Ki8` I was redirected to `https://www.matsa.no/i/image.phpimg=ph1Ki8?img=ph1Ki8`. Seems to be a problem with the question mark?

Comment: Just a note: The same did happen when I tried to access: `https://www.matsa.no/i/ph1Ki8`.

Comment: Just updated with `My new take on your problem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER --> updated again**

%{REQUEST_URI} only includes the URI **WITHOUT** the querystring. But this is stored in and can be retrieved in another variable --> %{QUERY_STRING}

I edited the code accordingly for the first .htaccess-file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

If you change your second .htaccess file to the following, it should be clean :)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/i/image.php
RewriteRule ^/i/(.*) /i/image.php?img=$1 [P,NC,L,QSA]
```

The [P] stands for 'proxy' meaning that your Apache is seen by the client as a proxy (ofc, without his notice), because your Apache executes the actual (correct) request, while the client only sees the result.

**My new take on your problem**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2$1 [R=Permanent,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^=]+)$ image.php?img=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, weird. That didn't work either am I afraid. Now `https://example.com/i/<imageID>` is redirected to `https://www.example.com/index.php`..

Comment: ok, then i gotta ask: you want to call http://example.com/i/<imageID> and get https://www.example.com/i/image.php?id=<imageID> as a result, but with http://example.com/i/<imageID> remaining in the browser?

Comment: No. When I added the client-proxy attribute and go to `http://example.com/i/<imageID>` I am being sent to `https://www.example.com/index.php`.

Here is a URL where you can see it in action: http://matsa.no/i/oZOchy

Comment: Okey, that works 50%. :)

Next problem: When I now go to `http://matsa.no/i/0EE8eo` I am now beeing sent to: `https://www.matsa.no/i/image.phpimg=0EE8eo?img=0EE8eo`

Comment: Because for RewriteRule in i-htaccess that seems appropiate^^ Can you specify when exactly this rewrite should be applied?

Comment: When people go to my front page and don't have either https or www they should be sent to the correct webpage (with https and www). I also have a image/file-sharing platform on the same webpage and there is here the problem is showing. So when for example you go to http://example.com/i/<imageID> you should first be sent to the https/www-version of the page and then it should send you to the /i/image.php?img=<imageID> (but the url should be the same, if that makes sense...). In this way I can send people a tiny link instead of the whole thing. :)

Comment: TL:DR;

1: `http://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

2: `https://www.example.com/i/<ID>` -> `https://www.example.com/i/image.php?img=<ID>` (the URL should stay the same as before).

Comment: got it, in a sec :)

Comment: I went through your requirements again and edited my post. Just commented out `#` the RewriteCond...An additional question: Apache 2.2 or 2.4?

Comment: I'm currently running on Apache 2.2.

Comment: I'd suggest to come back to this discussion and focus on one^^ But already updated my code again, forgot the leading /i/ for some reason and just to be certain I excluded /i/image.php from the rule to prevent loops. should also be achievable by Rewrite-Flag [END] instead of [L]

Comment: Tried to add the update, but again I'm getting 404. (`https://www.matsa.no/i/yJ9Exg`)

Comment: again :D added QSA for `query string append` so the parameter doesn't get lost

Comment: Btw. Where is the second .htaccess ment to be? Regarding to your code it should be in the directory _before_ /i/?

Comment: My code dosen't really care where the file is put. But for the `i-.htaccess` I'd search in the folder right above `i`

Comment: Okey, I will try that first. :)

Comment: Didn't work either.... This is just... weird... How about we take a teamviewer-session?

Comment: Since you don't have the chat privilige yet it might be the best way to go :(